# A small air compressor for cleaning?

Tags: hardware, compressor

I'm looking for a small air compressor for a small air compressor that I can use instead of a compressed air can for dusting my home electronics. From looking at websites like Amazon or Home Depot, most air compressors either fall into the 12V ones used for inflating car tires, or big, 10+ litre air compressors used for air-powered tools. I wonder if there are any small-form air compressors on the market that can store about a litre of air, deliver 100+ psi and work with some normal blowgun attachments?

Comment: There are lots of small compressors with tanks on the order of three gallons. Less than that  isn't very useful for anything larger than an airbrush.

Answer (score 1):

There are very small tank type units, but around 1gal is the smallest that seems to be available.

Here is one that is really small and quite reasonable, and from a reputable company.

You can gauge the size by the relationship of the typical pressure switch to the rest of the unit.

[http://www.amazon.com/Senco-PC1010-1-Horsepower-1-Gallon-Compressor/dp/B0000AQK78](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000AQK78)

[image]

Comment: That is small! Maybe 2 lbs.?

Comment: Looks like it. The specs should be on the site.

Comment: @ojait more like 20 lbs

Comment: It says 20 but I bet the item itself is under 15.

Answer (score 1):

For very small needs (which I'm assessing your stated needs as) a portable tank (3-5 gallons - 12-20 liters or so) which you either fill up at an air station or pump up with a standing bicycle pump is probably more sensible than a compressor.

[image: Air tank]

If you work out fittings for it and you really want only a liter or two, most plastic soda/pop/carbonated beverage bottles bottles are good for 160 PSI / 11 bar or so, though longevity will be better if you stick to 100 PSI/7bar or so. A standing bicycle type pump will fill one of those in short order.

[image: Bottle cap air fitting]

A third alternative would be an airbrush type/size compressor, but they don't typically do 100+ PSI.
[image: airbrush compressor]

Or, evidently, someone makes a thing targeted at exactly this market - more of a "blower" than a "compressor" but that being the desired end result....

https://www.metrovacworld.com/DataVac_Electric_Duster-ED500/overview

*Not associated with, owner of, or recommending any specific products shown, which are merely for example. I do own an air tank (not that one) and a bicycle pump, and something that might be an airbrush compressor one of these days when I get done refitting it, and which may grow a few soda bottles with air fittings in the caps to give it a reservoir.*

Answer (score 1):

While I have used an air compressor for dusting electronics, I don't recommend it.

Air compressors can sometimes spray out water or oil.  Especially if you forget to drain the tank frequently enough.  Most tools don't care about a little spray of water but electronics sure do.

For dusting electronics, you want something like this:
http://www.amazon.ca/Metro-ED500-MetrovAC-500watt-Electric/dp/B001J4ZOAW
(Not affiliated, just own a similar device.  No idea if thats a good one or not just the first one I found.)

The one I linked is expensive - just the first one I came across.  Mine cost under $50.

It gives at least as much air power as a brand new compressed gas duster, never runs out, and is nice and portable.  Also quieter than an air compressor (though still quite noisy).